# How do I hide the overflow from a jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an autocomplete that returns to many results, it often generates lists of 1000+, how do I set it to show only 10 rows at a time? I tried hiding it with css by setting max height and hiding the overflow but that causes the problem that the list looks small but still acts as a list with 1000+ and becomes slow.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                $(".searchCombogrid").combogrid({
                    url: '<%#Request.ApplicationPath%>/api/Arbetsorder/FindArbetsorder',
                    debug: true,
                    replaceNull: true,
                    position: { my: "right top", at: "right bottom" },
                    rememberDrag: true,
                    minLength: 0,
                    colModel: [
                    { 'columnName': 'Nr', 'hidden': 'true', 'width': '10', 'label': 'Nr' },
                    { 'columnName': 'Projekt', 'width': '60', 'label': 'Jobbnr' },
                    { 'columnName': 'AoNr', 'hidden': '20', 'label': 'AoNr' },
                    { 'columnName': 'Arbetsplats', 'width': '150', 'label': 'Arbetsplats' },
                    { 'columnName': 'Beskrivning', 'width': '150', 'label': 'Beskrivning' },
                    { 'columnName': 'BevakasAv', 'width': '70', 'label': 'Bevakas av' },
                    { 'columnName': 'ForetagsNamn', 'width': '70', 'label': 'Kund' }
                    ],
                    requestData: [
                    {
                        'verksamhetId': '<%#VerksamhetID%>',
                }
                ],
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $('#' + this.id).val(ui.item.Projekt);
                        __doPostBack(this.id, ui.item.Nr);

                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
$(".searchCombogrid").combogrid( "option", "rows", 20);
```

[**combogrid rows documentation here.**](http://combogrid.justmybit.com/options/rows.php)